# jQuery serialize() проверка GET запроса

Tags: php, jquery

Есть функция serialize() в jQuery, вопрос как провести проверку get запроса в php?

HTML

php код

```
   header ("Content-type: image/png");

   $write = $_GET["write"];
   $color = $_GET["color"];

   $img = imagecreatefrompng('template.png');
   $icon = imagecreatefrompng('10.png');

   $color = ImageColorAllocate($img, 30, 50, 80);

   //Название стикера
   ImageTTFText ($img, 12, 0, 20, 60, $color, "timesbd.ttf", $write);

   imagealphablending($img, false);
   imagesavealpha($img, true);
   ImagePng($img);
   imagedestroy($img);
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //PURE PATH TO IMAGE GENERATING PHP FILE
    var base = $(".preview img").attr("src");

    //GATHER IMAGE FOR FIRST TIME
    $(".preview img").attr("src",base+'?'+$("#realtime-form").serialize());

    //KEYUP EVENT AND NEW IMAGE GATHER
    $("#realtime-form input,textarea").stop().keyup(function(){
        $(".preview img").attr("src",base+'?'+$("#realtime-form").serialize()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Непонятно, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Не получается провести проверку в if() php закомментировал строку в коде выше

Comment: `if($_GET['a'] == 1) == 'black')` - это как понимать?

Comment: Извиняюсь поторопился, вот if($_GET['a'] == 'black') $color = ImageColorAllocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Верните проблемный код в вопрос :)